# Hilight object on mouse hover or mouse click events in Geoserver css style

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-css-module

How to hilighted object on mouse hover or mouse click events in Geoserver css style? Like a css :hover selector. Is it possible? Maybe it is doing after WMS/WFS?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible GeoServer's CSS is for styling the features in a WMS only, so the output is an image and there is no support for `:hover`.

Comment: How is it doing for GeoServer?

Comment: how is it doing what?

Comment: How is make hover event in Geoserver? Only with JS?

Comment: hover events are the clients problem not GeoServers